# Matching tuples in sql

Tags: sql, select, group-by, tuples

I am trying to write a query that matches a tuple of columns from a list. So let's say I have list of first names and last names and I want to match the combination of first and last name of the same index from the database.

```
first_names = ["Joe", "Freddy", "Michael"]
last_names = ["Jason", "Kruger", "Myers"]
```

In this case I want query to return some other column for a record that has either name "Joe Jason", "Freddy Kruger" or "Michael Myers".

For me, the obvious way is to group by first and last name and use group concat then match against concatenated field. But I want to try to avoid that. Is there anyway matching by tuples can be done in SQL?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some databases allow you to express this logic as:

```
where (firstname, lastname) in ( ('Joe', 'Jason'), ('Freddy', 'Kruger'),  ('Michael, 'Myers') )
```

In all, you can express this using boolean logic:

```
where (firstname = 'Joe' and lastname = 'Jason') or
      (firstname = 'Freddy' and lastname = 'Kruger') or
      (firstname = 'Michael' and lastname = 'Myers')
```